# SQLAlchemy multiple AND expression creates multiple selects on same entry

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to filter my query based on an expression like so:

```
self.query = self.query.filter(expression)
```

But when I filter it, the query adds the select statement twice, which in MYSQL causes an OperationalError: 1060 "Duplicate column name 'xxxx'. Here is my SQLAlchemy expression:

```
'"var__490__07McUdXtiy".response IS NOT NULL AND "var__490__07McUdXtiy".response != :param_1 AND "var__490__07McUdXtiy".response = :param_2'
```

It only happens when I have more than one AND in the expression. I have split the string in order to more clearly see the duplicate select. It is var__490__07McUdXtiy in the result below:

```
['SELECT auth_user.id AS auth_user_id',
 ' auth_user.password AS auth_user_password',
 ' auth_user.last_login AS auth_user_last_login',
 ' auth_user.is_superuser AS auth_user_is_superuser',
 ' auth_user.username AS auth_user_username',
 ' auth_user.first_name AS auth_user_first_name',
 ' auth_user.last_name AS auth_user_last_name',
 ' auth_user.email AS auth_user_email',
 ' auth_user.is_staff AS auth_user_is_staff',
 ' auth_user.is_active AS auth_user_is_active',
 ' auth_user.date_joined AS auth_user_date_joined',
 ' `var__490__07McUdXtiy`.response AS `07McUdXtiy_short`',
 ' `var__490__07McUdXtiy`.response AS `07McUdXtiy_short` \nFROM auth_user INNER JOIN reviewroom_reviewroomgroup_members ON reviewroom_reviewroomgroup_members.user_id = auth_user.id AND reviewroom_reviewroomgroup_members.reviewroomgroup_id IN (%s',
 ' %s) LEFT OUTER JOIN surveys_responsegroup AS survey__490 ON survey__490.user_id = auth_user.id AND survey__490.deleted = %s AND survey__490.survey_id = %s LEFT OUTER JOIN surveys_response AS `var__490__07McUdXtiy` ON `var__490__07McUdXtiy`.group_id = survey__490.id AND `var__490__07McUdXtiy`.question = %s \nWHERE `var__490__07McUdXtiy`.response IS NOT NULL AND `var__490__07McUdXtiy`.response != %s AND `var__490__07McUdXtiy`.response = %s']
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The BinaryExpression actually had two expression clauses and so the second clause created another select.